# Не работает PHP-скрипт

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN "http:w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <title> shporgalka_PHP </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$d="Вывод переменной $d произведён";
echo "$d";

$a = 4;
$b = 5;
$c = $a +$c;
echo $c

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Учу PHP второй день. Но как начал практиковаться, столкнулся с проблемой. Скрипт не работает. Работаю в Notepad++.

Comment: WTF?

На чем тестируете скрипт? как файл сохранен? ну и прочие нюансы разработки :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$d="Вывод переменной \$d произведён";
```

Если пишете в двойных кавычках нужно экранировать $ или же писать в одинарных кавычках.

```
echo $c;
```

Пропустили "**;**"

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо установить [**Denwer**](http://www.denwer.ru/) для того чтобы ваш PHP-код был обработан. Вы открываете обычный текстовый файл и смотрите его содержимое, а не открываете PHP-скрипт который обрабатывается веб-сервером.

**Установите Denwer!**

Answer (score 0):

Переменной $d надо присвоить значение перед тем как вставлять в строку.
Сделай так:

```
$d='Вывод переменной $d произведён';
echo "$d";
```

Тут другие кавычки. Это учитывается.
Во второй строке таже ошибка. Измени на:

```
$a = 4; $b = 5; $c = $a +$b; echo $c;
```

Answer (score 0):

$c = $a +$c - у тебя до этого с не определено, поставь перед этим с = 0; тогда и заработает

Comment: Тем php и славится, что переменную можно придумать налету :)

Comment: Исправил. Толку нет - как не выводится, так и не выводится. Пишу с помощью Notepad++. Сайт пока просто пишу.... Денвером и т.д не пользовался и не знаю, зачем они.

Comment: Что значит просто пока пишу сайт?

Поставь себе локально Апач+php+mysql для начала, ну а потом уже и пиши себе сайты.

Советую почитать про Апач и php в первую очередь.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$d='Вывод переменной $d произведён';// Одинарные кавычки!!!
echo $d;//Кавычки НЕ нужны

$a = 4;
$b = 5;
$c = $a +$c;//неопереденность с $c, выдаст нотис
echo $c

?>
```

Comment: Исправил. Толку нет - как не выводится, так и не выводится. Пишу с помощью Notepad++. Сайт пока просто пишу... Денвером и т.д не пользовался и не знаю зачем они.

Answer (score 0):

$a = 4, потом $b = 5, а дальше $c = $a +***$c*** - а где $c ??

Comment: Исправил. Толку нет - как не выводится, так и не выводится. Теперь код выглядит так. Пишу с помощью Notepad++. Сайт пока просто пишу... Денвером и т.д не пользовался и не знаю, зачем они.

Comment: Ну чувак ты крут, че сказать. ))) Ты знаешь, что такое PHP? Это язык программирования! PHP-скрипты обычно обрабатываются интерпретатором.
Оно у тебя есть? Самый банальный вариант - Denwer! В нем оно есть! Ну или если ты такой умный, то можешь сам установить отдельно!

P.S.: Notepad++ - это текстовый редактор, аналог Блокнота, а не интерпретатор и не компилятор!

Comment: И только потом минусуй!

Answer (score 0):

Я так понел человек не знает как и где php выполняется, php выполняется на сервере, вы открываете в браузере сайт и он отправляет запрос серверу о том что нужно выполнить php, его без сервера php запускать безсмыслеца...
Скачайте тотже денвер, он вам сделает локальный сервер, где вы можете выполнять свой сайт с php на ссылке http://localhost 
А потом уже как подтянетесь перенесете свой сайт на хостинг, хостинг php.